# Trying to find an array within another array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

So I have an array t and an array x. I'm trying to find the pattern "abc" of the array t inside the array x, which is at index 5 of the array. I've written this code so far but am lost as to why this is not working...

Also, I'm not allowed to use anything else but *while !=* or *while ==* in my code, making it a tad trickier. (Would've used a simple for loop otherwise).

Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args){


  char t[]={'a','b','c'};
  char x[]={'e','a','b','x','c','a','b','c'};
  int i=0, j=0, c=0;
  boolean a = false;
  while(i != x.length){
      if(t[0]!= x[i]){
          i++;
          continue;
      }
      else{
          j=0;
          while(j != t.length){
              if(t[j]==x[i+j])
              c++; j++;
          }
      if(c==t.length){
         a = true;
          break;
      }
      else{
          i=i+c-1;    
          c=0;
      }
  }
  if (a == true)
  System.out.println("index: "+i); 
  else
  System.out.println("Match not found");

  }
}
```

Comment: `boolean a` is always false here , right ?

Comment: Aside from the mistake in Akshay's answer, there's another big one, which you can find out by changing the definition of `t` to `char t[]={'a','b','c','d'};` and seeing what happens when you run it.

Comment: adding your if(a==true) outside while loop will help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    char t[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    char x[] = {'e', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'};

    int count = 0;
    while(count != x.length){
        if(x[count] != 'a'){
            count++;
        }else{
            if(x[count + 1] != 'b'){
                count++;
            }else{
                if(x[count + 2] != 'c'){
                    count++;
                }else{
                    System.out.println(count);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can you do this? This is much more simple!

Comment: The idea is to help the OP figure out what mistake he made, not to show off that you can solve the problem your own way.  And anyway, I think the idea is to figure out an algorithm that will work for whatever array you wish to search for, not one that's hardcoded to look for `{'a','b','c'}`.

Comment: This is obviously for a class.  If the instructor accepts this answer, they should be fired.

Comment: But the OP is already on a good start to finding a better algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Your code had 2-3 issues,

1. `boolean a` was never used
2. condition checking was inside the while loop(so on break, condition won't be checked)
3. length of array `x` should also be checked.

   ```
   char t[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
   char x[] = {'e', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'};
   int i = 0, j, c = 0;
   boolean a = false;
   while (i != x.length) {
       if (t[0] != x[i]) {
           i++;
       } else {
           j = 0;
           while (j != t.length && i+j<x.length) {
               if (t[j] == x[i + j]) {
                   c++;
               }
               j++;
           }
           if (c == t.length) {
               a = true;
               break;
           } else {
               i = i + c - 1;
               c = 0;
           }
       }

   }
   if (a) {
       System.out.println("index: " + i);
   } else {
       System.out.println("Match not found");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a very small mistake.

You are not setting a= true in your condition:

```
if(c==t.length){
    break;
}
```

Change your code to:

```
if(c==t.length){
    a = true;
    break;
}
```

Try this and it will work.

EDIT:

Another mistake you are doing is that you are keeping this condition inside while loop:

```
if (a == true)
  System.out.println("index: "+i); 
  else
  System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
```

Move it out of while loop and your original code works fine.

EDIT2:
As, agb pointed out, I agree that the code is prone to crashing because of missing checks and any change in input params t and x may give ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception.

Comment: Changed, oops! Still doesn't work... There should be index 5 printed in the end.

Comment: What is it printing?

Comment: I agree that the code is prone to crashing because of missing checks and any change in input params t and x may give ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception